# Embedded Youtube player only plays audio in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, youtube, playback

### **Issue**

The embedded Youtube flash player only plays audio and displays a black box where the video should be in Firefox.

---

**Site:**  [Nexus Gaming Media](http://nexus-media.org/)

To see the issue try playing the video that appears when the above home page is loaded (in Firefox). The audio works fine but there's a black box where the video should be.

Despite the above issue other embedded videos work fine for me in Firefox.  Such as the embedded video here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

**Tested flash player versions:** 11.6.602.180 and 11.7.700.141 (11.7 beta)

**What I've tried:**

- Re-installing the flash player
- Using the beta flash player
- Deleting all of the flash player cache files
- Multiple profiles in Firefox
- Modifying CSS values
- Using a private browsing window in Firefox
- Starting Firefox in safe mode with the default theme and all add-ons disabled

I cleared the history and cache after each modification and then I restarted the browser. The video playback works fine for me in Google Chrome (note that I have pepflashplayer disabled).  Does anyone have any idea what's causing the embedded player to work in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the wmode as a query string? (i.e. '?wmode=transparent')